# Error, when i install theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm getting following error when I install [emphaino theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/emphaino) in WordPress.

[image]

The default themes ( Twenty Eleven 1.3 , Twenty Ten 1.3 ) are working good. Other themes are also working good.

I already using same theme in another site. That's working good. But my new site makes this problem.

Where is Wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Wordpress version. Are you trying to use this theme with an older installation of Wordpress? If so, you may need to update Wordpress in order to use this theme.  The wp_get_theme function wasn't available until wordpress 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a local installation, but if not, it appears that a local path is being passed. Did you begin working in a WAMP stack, then migrate without changing a path perhaps?